# Yii2 how to save old informations to history-table?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

thanks for all stackoverflow members, I learned a lot from here.

I have a question about "beforeSave", I want save the old data to history-table in the database, for example if the user change anything I want save the old informations in the history-table.

Can anyone tell me what's the "best" scenario to achieve this ?

Thank you all and all suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the beforSave() function in your model.
Check if the param $insert is false theis mean you are updateing a record so 
     in this case you can  create a  new  HistoryModel, polutate and save

```
  public function beforeSave($insert)
  {
      if(parent::beforeSave($insert))
      {
          if(! $insert)
          {
              $historyModel = new History();
              $historyModel->att1 = $this->att1;
              $historyModel->att2 = $this->att2;
              ......
              $historyModel->attN = $this->attN;
              $historyModel->save();
              return true;
          }

      }
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#beforeSave%28%29-detail

Comment: @scaiEdge, do I need also a Controller or only a Model?

Comment: don't save in DB  the historyModel ?

Comment: you can try using  $historyModel->save(false); for disabling  validation  is the values are save then check for validation rules

Comment: thank you so much again :-) it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

For all others who want save only changes to Database here is the code:

```
  public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if(!$insert) {
        $historyModel = new History();
        if(isset($changedAttributes['attr1']  )){
            $historyModel->attr1 = $changedAttributes['attr1'];
        }
        ...
        $historyModel->save(false);
    }
}
```

Now you can save only the changes to database and not all records every time...